# In firefox browser, type_keys(locator,value) method from selenium escapes the last character from the "value" provided

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am working on selenium for automation web application testing.

I want make a key stroke event while entering the values in the textfield

I tried the following

```
@browser.type(auto_complete_field_locator, auto_complete_field_value)
@browser.type_keys(auto_complete_field_locator, auto_complete_field_value)
```

and it worked in the Internet Explorer 8 browser but it does not work in the Firefox.

```
@browser.type_keys(auto_complete_field_locator, auto_complete_field_value)
```

The type_keys method escapes the last character while entering value in to the text field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try typing  the string by each character's keycode:

```
@browser.type_keys(auto_complete_field_locator, "\119")
```

[Here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx) you can find the rest of the JavaScript keycodes.